# Automatic deployment of solutions with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I have a folder, containing several solutions for a SharePoint application, which I want to add and install. I want to iterate over the elements in the folder, then use the Add-SPSolution. After that I want to do a check if the solutions are done deploying, before using the Install-SPSolution. Here is a snippet that I am currently working on:

```
   # Get the location of the folder you are currently in
    $dir = $(gl)

    # Create a list with the .wsp solutions
    $list = Get-ChildItem $dir | where {$_.extension -eq ".wsp"}

    Write-Host 'DEPLOYING SOLUTIONS...'
    foreach($my_file in Get-ChildItem $list){Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath $my_file.FullName}

    Write-Host 'SLEEP FOR 30 SECONDS'
    Start-Sleep -s 30

    Write-Host 'INSTALLING SOLUTIONS...'
    foreach($my_file in Get-ChildItem $list){Install-SPSolution -Identity $my_file.Name -AllWebApplications -GACDeployment}
```

Is there a way to check if the deployment is finished, and it is ready to start installing the solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the [**SPSolution.Deployed** property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsolution.deployed.aspx) value in a loop - basic solution looks like this:

```
do { Start-Sleep 2 } while (!((Get-SPSolution $name).Deployed))
```

The [Deploying SharePoint 2010 Solution Packages Using PowerShell](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2010/06/deploying-sharepoint-2010-solution.html) article contains more details and [this comment](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2010/06/deploying-sharepoint-2010-solution.html?showComment=1289485497080#c8551657756245705509) discusses a potential caveat.